# Videos inside UICollectionView: scrolling issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, avplayerviewcontroller

I have some videos shown in UICollectionView; when the app is loaded it runs fine, while when the user scrolls the UICollectionView, videos are not loaded and all the cells are grayed and never be filled with the correct video, even if in debug i see the correct mp4 url.

Here is the code:

```
    func collectionView(cv: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let videoCell = collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("VideoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UICollectionViewCell

        var aPlayer = AVPlayer()
        let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        let item = self.wall[indexPath.row]

        print("URL:"+item.video_link)

        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: item.video_link)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        aPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: fileUrl!)

        moviePlayerController.player = aPlayer
        moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoCell!.frame.size.width, videoCell!.frame.size.height)
        moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        moviePlayerController.view.sizeToFit()
        moviePlayerController.player?.actionAtItemEnd=AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                         selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
                                                         name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                                                         object: moviePlayerController.player!.currentItem)
        moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        moviePlayerController.player?.play()
        /*
        videoCell?.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
        videoCell!.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
        */
        videoCell!.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)
        })
        return videoCell!
    }
```

Can anyone help me to understand the problem?

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should add subviews to `videoCell!.contentView` not `videoCell` itself.
2. You're adding lots of `moviePlayerController.view` s into one single cell! `cellForItemAtIndexPath` gets called whenever a cell is about to be shown, but it does not mean that after dequeuing you'll have a clean cell, it might be on of previous cells that is not displayed in screen anymore. have a `Bool` or check `videoCell!.subviews.count` to determine if you've previously added a `moviePlayerController.view` or not. If you've added it already, change the url (if possible) or delete it, and add it again.

p.s: The best way to go is define a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class.